# How to implement a Java plugin system allows both fast development and integrated deployment?

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-boot, apache-spark

In a typical Spark development cycle, I can write the normal JVM program (the Spark driver) right inside the IDE. It is possible to run/debug/unit test my program without deploying it to the Spark.

Only after I finished the program, packaged it as a JAR, and issue commands to deploy it to the Spark without restarting/interrupting the Spark itself. The Spark is aware of my Jar and is able to pick it up. The functionalities of the program in both the development and deployment stages are exactly the same.

How is that possible? Can I do this kind of thing like in a Spring Boot program where the main program defines some @Entities and @Repositories, etc., and other programs are able to use/extend these classes in a standalone way (in development) as well as acting as a plugin (in deployment)?

Is there any better way other than this approach?